# Unity: trying to transfer material from one object to another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to change game objects, specifically Cubes, to change material during run-time.

Rather then trying to search for material by name, I decided to try a different approach, assign a few game objects with pre-set materials, then when I want to change material of something, I am trying to get it from those pre-made objects.

I already spent some time trying to fix that, found a few possible mistakes, fixed them, but I still don't get the result I need.

And I also use debugging, will give more information below.

So, I first created a few Materials as global variables.

```
public Material MaterialGrass;
public Material MaterialRock;
public Material MaterialSand;
public Material MaterialWater;
```

Then, I am trying to load actual materials from pre-set game objects.

```
    GameObject MainVariablesObject = GameObject.Find("MainVariablesObject");
    GlobalVariablesScript thisGlobalVariablesScript = MainVariablesObject.GetComponent<GlobalVariablesScript>();

    thisGlobalVariablesScript.MaterialGrass = GameObject.Find("GrassTexture").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[0];
    thisGlobalVariablesScript.MaterialRock = GameObject.Find("RockTexture").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[0];
    thisGlobalVariablesScript.MaterialSand = GameObject.Find("SandTexture").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[0];
    thisGlobalVariablesScript.MaterialWater = GameObject.Find("WaterTexture").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[0];
```

The game view is divided into 9 squares.

```
    GameObject CubeFront0 = GameObject.Find("CubeFront0");
    GameObject CubeFront1 = GameObject.Find("CubeFront1");
    GameObject CubeFront2 = GameObject.Find("CubeFront2");
    GameObject CubeLeft0 = GameObject.Find("CubeLeft0");
    GameObject CubeLeft1 = GameObject.Find("CubeLeft1");
    GameObject CubeLeft2 = GameObject.Find("CubeLeft2");
    GameObject CubeRight0 = GameObject.Find("CubeRight0");
    GameObject CubeRight1 = GameObject.Find("CubeRight1");
    GameObject CubeRight2 = GameObject.Find("CubeRight2");
```

And now the part that I still didn't manage to solve:

```
public static void DisplayPlayerView()
{
    GameObject MainVariablesObject = GameObject.Find("MainVariablesObject");
    GlobalVariablesScript thisGlobalVariablesScript = MainVariablesObject.GetComponent<GlobalVariablesScript>();

    DefineTexturesSources();
    GetSurroundingCells();

    GameObject CubeFront0 = GameObject.Find("CubeFront0");
    GameObject CubeFront1 = GameObject.Find("CubeFront1");
    GameObject CubeFront2 = GameObject.Find("CubeFront2");
    GameObject CubeLeft0 = GameObject.Find("CubeLeft0");
    GameObject CubeLeft1 = GameObject.Find("CubeLeft1");
    GameObject CubeLeft2 = GameObject.Find("CubeLeft2");
    GameObject CubeRight0 = GameObject.Find("CubeRight0");
    GameObject CubeRight1 = GameObject.Find("CubeRight1");
    GameObject CubeRight2 = GameObject.Find("CubeRight2");

    GameObject[] Cubes = new GameObject[] { CubeFront0, CubeFront1, CubeFront2,
                                            CubeLeft0, CubeLeft1, CubeLeft2,
                                            CubeRight0, CubeRight1, CubeRight2};

    char[] Map = new char[] { thisGlobalVariablesScript.Front0, thisGlobalVariablesScript.Front1, thisGlobalVariablesScript.Front2,
                              thisGlobalVariablesScript.Left0, thisGlobalVariablesScript.Left1, thisGlobalVariablesScript.Left2,
                              thisGlobalVariablesScript.Right0, thisGlobalVariablesScript.Right1, thisGlobalVariablesScript.Right2};

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        Material thisMaterial = Cubes[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[0];
        //MeshRenderer thisMaterial = Cubes[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

        if (Map[i] == 'G')
            thisMaterial = thisGlobalVariablesScript.MaterialGrass;
        if (Map[i] == 'R')
            thisMaterial = thisGlobalVariablesScript.MaterialRock;
        if (Map[i] == 'S')
            thisMaterial = thisGlobalVariablesScript.MaterialSand;
        if (Map[i] == 'W')
            thisMaterial = thisGlobalVariablesScript.MaterialWater;

        Cubes[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[0] = thisMaterial;

        Debug.Log(Cubes[i].name + " " + Cubes[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[0]);
    }
```

What I found by placing those Debug.Log commands:

1) All game objects I try to "Find" exist, there is no error here.

2) "thisMaterial" gets the correct material, so I think there is no problem with defining materials as variables, and getting correct data.

3) I no longer get error that material isn't attached.

4) Inside the "for" loop, the "thisMaterial" shows new and correct data, and "Cubes[i].GetComponent().materials[0]" shows old data - materials I set by hand in the beginning.

5) The data in array "Map" is correct.

What I am missing?

Comment: Just in general: Try to avoid all the `Find` and `GetComponent` calls and instead get them as soon as possible e.g. in `Awake` or `Start`. And if possible already reference stuff in the Inspector! Why not simply reference your Materials e.g. in the GlobalVariablesScript directly? Also note that you could simply use `MeshRenderer.material` instead of `materials[0]` and there is also a difference between `material` (using an instance of the material -> change only affects this object) and `sharedMaterial` (using the same original material -> change in material affects all users)

Comment: Use `MeshRenderer.sharedMaterial` unless you want that renderer to clone the material and use the clone. Unity does this automatically because it assumes that by asking for the `material` not the `sharedMaterial` that you want to break batching.

Comment: `but I still don't get reply I need.` could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: This worked, I changed: "materials[0]" to "SharedMaterials[0]". @derHugo or Draco18s, please post your suggestions as answers, so I can upvote them.